# Incrementar números ao nome do ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde pessoal, preciso de uma ajuda, tenho a seguinte condição, após clicar em um botão devo inserir um novo checkbox e o primeiro destes checkbox tem um id="0", o seguinte precisa ter id="1", id="2", assim sucessivamente, sempre após clicar no botão que insere um novo checkbox. Exemplo:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="0">
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click','.add',function(){
  //acrescentar novo checkbox com id="1"
  //acrescentar novo checkbox com id="2"
});
```

Comment: Id's puramente numéricos não são muito boa prática, tanto é que em versões anteriores do html não eram validos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenha alguma `div` para manipular que isso ficará fácil.
Crie uma variável para adicionar sempre um `id` novo. No meu caso, usei o `i`;
Dentro da função de `click` do botão que irá usar, adicione o evento de `.append` para a `div` recebedora do novo elemento, conforme o código abaixo:

```
var i = 0;    
$('.buttonQueClicou').on('click', function() {
    $('.divParaManipular').append('<input type="checkbox" id="'+i+'" />');
    i++;
});

<button value="add" class="buttonQueClicou" />    
<div class="divParaManipular">
<!-- SEUS CHECKBOX ENTRARÃO AQUI -->
</div>
```

Comment: Seria mais interessante postar uma resposta comentando o que cada funcionalidade faz.

Comment: Obrigado Diego!

Comment: @LeAndrade, apenas criei uma variável para incrementar quando for adicionar um novo elemento no click do botão.

Comment: Disponha, @MunirBaarini! ;)

Comment: @LeAndrade, feito! Veja se dá pra entender... abraço e boa sorte.

Comment: Jóia man, apenas comentei devido o fato de pessoas que querem aprender pesquisam algo parecido e tem uma maneira fácil de se entender, como está sendo feito aquilo.

Answer (score 3):

Simples, primeiro você precisará colocar os inputs em uma `div`, depois criará uma variável contadora, declarei ela como `cont`,
após, capture o evento `click`, e vai dando um `append` do elemento na `div` criada.

Pra finalizar, basta ir incrementando o contador.

Resultado:

```js
let cont = 1;
$('#btn-add').on('click',function(){
    $('.checks').append('<input type="checkbox" id="'+cont+'">')
    cont++;
});
```

```html
<div class="checks">
  <input type="checkbox" id="0">
</div>
<button id="btn-add"> Adicionar </button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Caro `downvote`, poderia me informar aonde eu errei? Gostaria de entender para poder concertar.

Comment: **Não foi meu o downvote**, mas, creio que a sua resposta esteja basicamente igual a da resposta acima que foi postada antes.

Comment: E por isso considerada `cópia?` Eu estava respondendo quando não tinha nenhuma resposta, apenas demorei para postar

Comment: Pois é, tbm acho acho que não seja motivo para o downvote.